# El Capiton Xcode 6.3.2 not giving options to choose Schemes

Tags: xcode7, osx-elcapitan

I have installed El Capitan recently. I was trying to compile one of my applications on Xcode 6.3.2 in El Capitan. But the problem I noticed is, there is no option to choose the schemes on Xcode.

[image: Xcode 6.3.2, on El Capitan]

But on Xcode 7, it looks fine.

[image: Xcode 7 El Capitan]

Did anyone face the same problem? 
If yes, did you guys just migrate to new Xcode or there is a way to solve this?

Happy Coding

Comment: Does Xcode 6 support El Capitan?

Comment: Yes, everything worked fine if except this problem.

Comment: But Apple acknowledge issues with Xcode 6, and advise using Xcode 7, don't they?